# How to parse a JSON dictionary and put the keys and values in separate arrays - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, xcode8

I'm trying to parse www.fixer.io JSON to get currency data. I've been having trouble parsing the JSON and trying to separate the keys and values from the "rates" dictionary. I need them separate so I can put them in arrays to display the currency name (ex: USD, EUR, JPN) and their respective rates.

I've read that I have to use the "allKeys" and "allValues" to do this but so far I'm having no luck. Any ideas?

```
NSURL *fixerURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fixerURL];
NSError *error;

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *names;
    NSArray *rates;


    for (names in json) {
        names = [json allKeys];
        for (rates in json) {
            rates = [json allValues];
        }
        [arr addObject:names];
        [arr2 addObject:rates];
    }
    self.currencyList = arr;
    self.currencyRates = arr2;
    [self updateTableView];
```

Here is the JSON ---> http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD

Comment: i get the errr `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'`

Comment: can you attach ur project

Comment: Sure, although i don't see a button to attach my project. How would I do that?

Comment: @Matthew Guest your problem is solve or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

```
NSURL *fixerURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD"];
    NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fixerURL];
    NSError *error;

    NSDictionary *json1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",json1);
    NSDictionary *json = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[json1 objectForKey:@"rates"]];
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[json allKeys]];
    NSMutableArray *arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[json allValues]];
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);
    NSLog(@"%@",arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

as the **rates** key contains a dictionary not an array so we can’t get country name and currency as dictionary format 
if you want to get the country name and currency in different array so you need to get them separately like bellow

```
NSArray *arrKeys = [[json valueForKey:@"rates"] allKeys];
NSArray *arrValues = [[json valueForKey:@"rates"] allValues];
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `JSON` response you have to get yoiur all currency rate as below

```
NSMutableArray *allCurrencyKey = [[json valuesForKey:@"rates"] allKeys];

NSMutableArray *allRates = [json valueForKey:@"rates"];

for(NSString *strCurKey in allCurrencyKey)
{
   NSLog (@" %@ rate is %@ ", strCurKey, [allRates valueForKey :strCurKey ]);
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what error you're getting, but when I try to run this code I get data coming back as nil. Which of course crashes the app.

It probably has something to do with the method you are using to fetch the JSON.
dataWithContentsOfURL: should not be used for network-based URLs.
[dataWithContentsOfURL:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1547245-datawithcontentsofurl)

To fetch data over the network, take a look at [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession).

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get Rates Nad Currency Names

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

By this response you can get all rates:

```
NSMutableDictionary *rates = [json objectForKey:@"rates"];

//Get All Currency Names by `allKeys`.
NSArray *currencyTitles = [rates allKeys];

for(NSString *currencyName in currencyTitles){

    //Get Value.
    NSString *aStrCurValue = [rates objectForKey:currencyName];
}
```

Comment: I get an error with the allKeys and object for key. it says no visible @interface for NSMutableArray declares the selector 'objectForKey'/'allKeys'. Any idea why?

Comment: Please check my updated answer as your rates JSON is kind of dictionary.